# Is kernel regression the same as linear kernel regression?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression

i wanted to code the linear kernel regression in sklearn so i made this code :

```
model = LinearRegression()
weights = rbf_kernel(X_train,X_test)

for i in range(weights.shape[1]):
    model.fit(X_train,y_train,weights[:,i])
    model.predict(X_test[i])
```

then i found that there is KernelRidge in sklearn :

```
model = KernelRidge(kernel='rbf')

model.fit(X_train,y_train)

pred = model.predict(X_train)
```

my question is:
1-what is the difference between these 2 codes?
2-in model.fit() that come after KernelRidge(), i found in the documentation that  i can add a third argument "weight" to fit() function, i would i do that if i already applied a kernel function to the model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. What is the difference between these two code snippets?

Basically, they have nothing in common. Your first code snippet implements **linear regression**, with arbitrary set weights of samples. (How did you even come up with calling `rbf_kernel` this way?) This is still just a linear model, nothing more. You simply assigned (a bit randomly) which samples are important and then looped over features (?). This makes no sense at all. In general: what you have done with `rbf_kernel` is simply wrong; this is completely not how it is supposed to be used (and why it gave you errors when you tried to pass it to the fit method and you ended up doing a loop and passing each column separately).

Example of fitting such a model to data which is a cosine (thus 0 in mean):

[image: lr]

> 2. I found in the documentation for the `model.fit()` function that comes after `KernelRidge()` that I can add a third argument, `weight`. Would I do that if I had already applied a kernel function to the model?

This is **actual kernel method**, kernel **is not samples weighting**. (One might use kernel function to assign weights, but this is not the meaning of kernel in "linear kernel regression" or in general "kernel methods".) Kernel is a method of introducing nonlinearity to the classifier, which comes from the fact that many methods (including linear regression) can be expressed as dot products between vectors, which can be substituted by kernel function leading to solving the problem in different space (Reproducing Hilbert Kernel Space), which might have very high complexity (like the infinite dimensional space of continuous functions induced by the RBF kernel).

Example of fitting to the same data as above:

[image: kernel]

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.kernel_ridge import KernelRidge
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

X = np.linspace(-10, 10, 100).reshape(100, 1)
y = np.cos(X)

for model in [LinearRegression(), KernelRidge(kernel='rbf')]:

    model.fit(X, y)
    p = model.predict(X)

    plt.figure()
    plt.title(model.__class__.__name__)
    plt.scatter(X[:, 0], y)
    plt.plot(X, p)

    plt.show()
```

Comment: first thank you i realised my mistakes 
as i know now is that:

using kernel in "kernel regression" is not like using kernel in "locally weighted linear regression"
in "kernel regression" we use it as a weight for the distances between x0 and X,
"kernel regression" here is lazy learner

but in "kernal linear regression" we use it as a a method of introducing nonlinearity to the model 
"kernal linear regression" is eager learner

Comment: no, "kernel regression" is not about weighting anything. "kernel regression" is a "bag term" for any reggresion using kernel trick, thus "kernel linear regression" is a specific type of "kernel regression", as well as "support vector regression". Using kernels for computing weights is not "kernel regression".

Comment: the weights in the fit function is just weights for the data to construct the the regression line 
in the gradient descent (like the weights in data when we use boosting) but how can i add the weight term to the closed form solution of linear regression  \beta = (K(X^T,X) + \lambda I)^{-1}y

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_regression   ,i think its name is Nadaraya–Watson kernel regression , it's written "using a kernel as a weighting function"

Comment: is there a difference between "kernal linear regression" and "locally weighted linear regression"

Comment: these are completely different objects. What you are refering to is kernel density estimation used for regression (this is completely different notion of kernel than in "typical" ML), again - that has nothing to do with what you constructed using sklearn. You are refering here to the name used 40 years ago, which drifted completely since then, leading to confusions. In particular, this is more related to localy weighted LR, which is completely different object from the both code snippets you presentsed (and is absent in scikit-learn)

Comment: your answers are really amazing thank you so much
now i understood that "Nadaraya–Watson kernel regression" is an old name it had been replaced by "local weighted linear regression"
both of them uses "kernel density estimation" which is not like the "typical" kernel in ML ,right?

Comment: -but i wanted to say something about my first code snippet:
rbf_kernel(X,y) will calculate the rbf kernel(used kernel as a "kernel density estimation") on the differnce(distance) between them 
the number of columns is the number of instances in y 
in the loop i wanted to each time i construct a line i want that line to weight some points more(the resulting weights from the kernel function)
and then i will predict only 1 point every time. why is that gives me wrong predictions?

Comment: I don't think all this harsh language is necessary.

Comment: I don't think all this harsh language is necessary.

The "kernel" in both cases comes from the same idea. The "kernel" in linear operator theory that supports the "kernel trick" comes directly from the covariance operator underlying the "kernel regression" the OP refers to. "Kernel Regression" is a perfectly legitimate term for statistical models, and still has value as a type of generalized smoothing of scatter plots (like a more computationally intense version of LOESS).

The fact that the term is also used in a different context doesn't make "Kernel Regression" qua EV approx. invalid.